# How to add vCard's base 64 string to vCalendar

Tags: ios, google-app-engine, contacts, icalendar, vcf-vcard

According to the following article:
[iPhone: how to get safari to recognize a vcard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1892373/iphone-how-to-get-safari-to-recognize-a-vcard)
http://mobicontact.info/iphone/download-contact-from-web-page/

I generated ics file (vCalendar) with content of vcf file (vCard) inside. Mean that:
I encoded vcf file's content to Base64 and then put its into ics file, after "X-APPLE-FILENAME=iphonecontact.vcf:".
But iPod can't recoginze the contact in vCard file. 
However, if I put base 64 string (hard code, not generate by vcf file's content) in ics file then everything ok, like: http://iphone.mobicontact.info/ (select Download contact to Iphone)
Please help me to resolve this issue.
Thanks everybody!
Note that: I develop on Google App Engine with Java environment.

Comment: So what's the difference between what you're generating and the working version?

Comment: I agree with Evert - should be easy to diagnose if you just compare the two outputs. Be careful to include a space at the start of the line as described in my php files.  Can you post the two versions and I'll see what I can find.`$vcard = file_get_contents("iphonecontact.vcf");$b64vcard = base64_encode($vcard);$b64mline = chunk_split($b64vcard,74,"\n");$b64final = preg_replace('/(.+)/', ' $1', $b64mline);`