# iOS 7 vCard header issue with InAppBrowser

Tags: header, ios7, vcf-vcard, inappbrowser

With iOS 7 it´s now possible to export vCards the normal way.

(Take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11405271/2861693)

My header hence looks like this

```
case "ios_seven":

header("Content-Type: text/x-vcard; charset=utf-8");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\".".utf8_decode($this->contact->getLastName())."..vcf\";");

echo $vcard;

break;
```

and works really great when opening the webapp with safari. But as soon as I call it with an inappbrowser (which is a common case because the link is retrieved by scanning a qr-code), it fails loading...

Somebody got an idea for an inappbrowser-compatible header for exporting vCards?

Best Regards, Erdan.

Answer (score 0):

If you change the "Content-Type" header to "text/vcard", it may work.