# Share VCF file through Whatsapp and Other Apps iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, uidocumentinteraction, whatsapp, vcf-vcard

I am developing an application that generates vcf files for the contacts. 
Now, I want to share that vcf file to others through whatsapp, or any other supported app that can share that vcf file.

I used `UIDocumentInteractionController`

but it is displaying a limited "open in..." options.

Even the iPhone Contacts app doesn't have this option, but the other smart phones now-a-days have this kind of feature.

I have used public.item UTI for `UIDocumentInteractionController` but this is opening other apps and not opening whatsapp. I mean If I use public.image as UTI the controller can show whatsapp, but actually I need to share the Vcard, not the image. :-)

Or at least can we share a .txt file in whats app? I think whats app iOS is not allowing this.

Comment: Have a look at this [stackoverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18635070/how-to-get-a-vcard-vcf-file-into-ios6-contacts-from-website) and [StackOverFlow Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1892373/iphone-how-to-get-safari-to-recognize-a-vcard) here.

Comment: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/22177/importing-vcards-from-a-website-into-ioss-contacts-app

Comment: Thank you. This is working fine with my app. But, My app needs to share the vcard to other apps along contacts app.