# Adding vCard to Contacts in iOS 13

Tags: contacts, ios13, vcf-vcard

we have a web site that allows people to click on a link to a vCard .vcf file to install contact details on their phone. The method for handling this has changed in iOS 13 and it is really confusing people. Previously, the vCard opened in the Contacts app and there was a Save button to add it to contacts. Simple, and people understood it. Now the vCard opens in a preview, but there is no obvious way to save it to their contacts. They have to know to tap the Actions icon, then find the Contacts entry and tap that. Very few people can work that out, instead they just tap the Done button, thinking it has been added. Adding a vCard to your contacts has become too hard for most people to work out.

Does anyone know of a trick whereby we can skip the preview screen and open the vCard directly in the Contacts app?

Gary

Comment: Did you find anything helpful other than using QR codes or calendar events?

Comment: No, looks like this is the way it is now.

Comment: Also, if the user has deleted the Contacts App (like I did) there is no possible way to add it and it’s unclear why.

Answer (score 2):

Including vCard information within a QR code as plain text (not a linked .vcard file) prompts users to add this information to their contacts app—a simple user experience for both iOS and Android users.

From what I've found, requesting any iOS or Android user to download a .vcard file leads to a confusing user experience which should be avoided.

Not sure how helpful you'd find it to include a QR code on a mobile website, but it's one option you have.

Comment: I agree, importing a .vcf file on mobile has never been easy, but Apple have now made it unfathomable for most people.

Answer (score 0):

You might try to embed the vcard in an ical element like described in [iPhone: how to get safari to recognize a vcard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1892373/iphone-how-to-get-safari-to-recognize-a-vcard)