# Write to text file in html

Tags: javascript, html

I wanted to try giving an output to a file using a Small screen on HTML. Everytime I click on the button I want the text in the file to be replaced. This is the code I wrote:

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>This is Web App</title>
</head>
<script>
function createDoc()
{
var doc=document.open("answer.txt","replace");
var txt="<html><body>You clicked Allow</body></html>";
doc.write(txt);
doc.close();
}

function createDoc2()
{
var doc=document.open("answer.txt","replace");
var txt="<html><body>You clicked Deny</body></html>";
doc.write(txt);
doc.close();
}
</script>

<body>
<h1> This is the visitor at your house</h1>
<img src = "./images/chef.gif" width="130" height="101" />
<br />
<button name="Yes" type="button" onclick="createDoc()">Allow! </button>
<button name="No" type="button" onclick="createDoc2()">Deny! </button>


</body>
</html>
```

I know it is not the correct way to do it but am trying to learn. Please help me and point out my mistakes and tell me how to correct them if possible. I know there might be plenty. I am just trying to teach myself at this point. Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: I didn't know this was even possible o.O

Comment: Uh, that's because you can't. There's the HTML5 File API, but that doesn't sound like what you're trying to do. That would be a HUGE security risk...

Comment: @tjameson I had an idea it wont work but wanted to try. Is there some way like sending a Get Request or something and doing this?

Comment: [This is possible using HTML5.](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2011/08/Saving-generated-files-on-the-client-side)

Comment: @Derek - I mentioned that, but I don't think it will do what the OP wants. The FileWriter API is just used for saving to a sandbox if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: @tjameson - You should try the demo first. http://eligrey.com/demos/FileSaver.js/

Comment: Didn't work on Opera or Firefox (used data uri hack), but worked on Chrome. I stand corrected.

Comment: @tjameson - I only know it works on Chrome, and I only have Chrome, so   I don't know if it works on FF or Opera. :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to download a file generated by your page, this question may help:

[Download data url file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3916191/download-data-url-file)

The idea is that you need to encode your data as base64 (not hard, modern browsers support [btoa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3916191/download-data-url-file)) and direct the browser to open it. If you trick it by giving the file a mime-type it doesn't know how to open (such as `application/octet-steam`), it will download the file instead of displaying it.

The problem with this solution is that you cannot name the file.

If you want to name the file, I'd `POST` the data to your webserver, write it to a file on the server, then do a `window.open` with the path to the file. This will allow you to download the file in question.

There's a draft in progress to allow Javascript to write to a file directly, but this file will be in a sandboxed location that users don't have direct access to. This is only for web-apps to store large amounts of data on the client. From your question, this is likely not what you want. Try one of the above solutions.

Comment: [HTML5Rocks - Saving-generated-files-on-the-client-side](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2011/08/Saving-generated-files-on-the-client-side)

Comment: @Derek- `though unfortunately it will eventually be removed from the spec`. Nothing supports this.

Comment: They are not removing it according to [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/file-writer-api/#the-filesaver-interface).

Comment: @Derek - From the spec: `Since this is intended to be used only with the sandboxed filesystem...`. Sounds like you won't be able to save to an arbitrary location on the client.

Comment: We are not using the `FileWriter` here, we are using the `FileSaver`. `The FileSaver(data) constructor takes one argument: the Blob of data to be saved to a file.`

Comment: As posted elsewhere, only supported on Chrome. And it's still just a working draft.

Comment: If HTML5 is not acceptable, then telling the server to do all this is the way to go.

Comment: @Derek: I understand these approaches a little bit. The one with blobBuilder is nice. Just another question if you dont mind. Since you said that it's almost not possible (with the exception of your example) to save a file on client machine, Is it easier to write to a file on the Server? How can I do that considering the code above?

Comment: @And_Learner - You will have to use AJAX or `POST` to tell your server to write/create files, then return back that URL to the file. On the server side, you can use PHP, JavaScript, or other languages you want to achieve this.

Comment: Thanks Derek and tjameson. Your help is much appreciated.