# how to create an image file on server from dataurl

Tags: javascript, image, data-url

I have an image in a dataurl format, like:

```
data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBDAAMCAgMCAgMDAwMEAwME…iiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigD/2Q==
```

I need to convert this string in JavaScript to another string which can be directly copied to a blank jpg file so that it can be viewed by the user.
Any idea how to achieve this?

Comment: You need to display it or create a file?

Comment: create a file. @jclandero23

Comment: Is [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5100158/2133379) what you're trying to do?

Comment: No, I edit the question now to be more clear

Answer (score 3):

You just need to remove "data:image/jpeg;base64," from DataURI.

```
$dataUri = "data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBDAAMCAgMCAgM...";
// remove "data:image/jpeg;base64," from image Data URI.
$data = str_replace("data:image/jpeg;base64,", "", $dataUri);

// save to file
file_put_contents("/tmp/image.jpeg", base64_decode($data));
```

Comment: `file_put_contents` isn't really helpful pseudocode. The question is how to create an image file, not how to prep your data for later use in an image file.

Answer (score 1):

To display it you can use the src attribute:

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,R0lGODlhUAAPAKIAAA+g4JADs=" width="80" height="80" />
```

To generate a file you need use canvas element:

Example:

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <canvas id="c"></canvas>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="canvas2image.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="baseg4.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            var canvas = document.getElementById("c");
            var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

            var image = new Image();
            image.src = "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KG............5CYII%3D";
            image.onload = function()
            {
               ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
                var foo = Canvas2Image.saveAsPNG(canvas);  
            };
            var img = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

And save the image and stuff... you can find a way to convert the canvas to a file in this link:

// http://www.nihilogic.dk/labs/canvas2image/

EDIT: New link, I guess...
https://github.com/hongru/canvas2image

Comment: there is typeError in ctx.drawImage(data, 0, 0);

Comment: I made some edit on the post! try now! =D  Now works for me! =)

Comment: Looks like the canvas2image link is broken.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the user to be be able to download the file and save it somewhere on their computer, try this:

```
document.location.href = "data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQAB…";
```

See [Download data url file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3916191/download-data-url-file) if this is what you're trying to do.

Comment: I don't wanna download it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove `data:image/jpeg;base64,` from the `dataURI` and decode the `dataURI`:

```js
public void saveImage(String imageURI) {
    BufferedImage image = null;
    String blobString=imageString.replace("data:image/jpeg;base64,", "");
    byte[] byteArray = Base64.getDecoder().decode(blobString);
    ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(byteArray);
    try {
        image = ImageIO.read(bis);
        File file = new File("/home/rakesh/Vinay/a.jpeg");
        ImageIO.write(image, "jpeg", file);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```