# Create image file using js (NOT PHP)

Tags: javascript, createfile

I have a question.
In my web app I create an image file using a little php script.
It is possible to create a file and re-use it with js?

Thanks.

I find some script that convert canvas2image.
The main problem is that I wolud save the image in my path (localhost/myproj/photos) and not in download folder.
It is a way to do that?
Thans in advise.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to create an image file on server from dataurl](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15675063/how-to-create-an-image-file-on-server-from-dataurl)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't got experience myself, but it's should be possible to load an external image into a canvas object and to export that object as a base64 string.

After that you could save that string to a client-side database with a js library such as PouchDB.

A example of loading external images into canvas is here: [HTML Canvas image to Base64 problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7099381/html-canvas-image-to-base64-problem)