# Save Canvas as Image Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, todataurl

I've built a couple of web resources to add signature functionality to a Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011 form one bit built in silverlight as a file uploader etc. and the other in javascript and HTML to do the signature on the screen and save as an image but the code only works in google chrome.

I've done some reading around looked on endless amounts of stackoverflow threads but can't find any answers.

Is there anyway in which I can somehow either

- save the canvas image in IE, the way the current solution already works in chrome
- Open up a new window so the canvas image appears and can be right clicked and saved

I've tried doing both of the above already but had no luck.

**It has to be in javascript also**

```
    <html><head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var canvas, ctx, flag = false,
        prevX = 0,
        currX = 0,
        prevY = 0,
        currY = 0,
        dot_flag = false;

    var x = "black",
        y = 2;

    function init() {
        canvas = document.getElementById('can');
        ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        w = canvas.width;
        h = canvas.height;

        canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", function (e) {
            findxy('move', e)
        }, false);
        canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", function (e) {
            findxy('down', e)
        }, false);
        canvas.addEventListener("mouseup", function (e) {
            findxy('up', e)
        }, false);
        canvas.addEventListener("mouseout", function (e) {
            findxy('out', e)
        }, false);
    }

    function color(obj) {
        switch (obj.id) {
            case "black":
                x = "black";
                break;
            case "white":
                x = "white";
                break;
        }
        if (x == "white") y = 50;
        else y = 2;

    }

    function draw() {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(prevX, prevY);
        ctx.lineTo(currX, currY);
        ctx.strokeStyle = x;
        ctx.lineWidth = y;
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.closePath();
    }

    function erase() {
        var m = confirm("Want to clear");
        if (m) {
            ctx.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);
            document.getElementById("canvasimg").style.display = "none";
        }
    }

    function findxy(res, e) {
        if (res == 'down') {
            prevX = currX;
            prevY = currY;
            currX = e.clientX - canvas.offsetLeft;
            currY = e.clientY - canvas.offsetTop;

            flag = true;
            dot_flag = true;
            if (dot_flag) {
                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.fillStyle = x;
                ctx.fillRect(currX, currY, 2, 2);
                ctx.closePath();
                dot_flag = false;
            }
        }
        if (res == 'up' || res == "out") {
            flag = false;
        }
        if (res == 'move') {
            if (flag) {
                prevX = currX;
                prevY = currY;
                currX = e.clientX - canvas.offsetLeft;
                currY = e.clientY - canvas.offsetTop;
                draw();
            }
        }
        }

            function downloadCanvas(link, canvasId, filename) {
var test = document.getElementById(canvasId).toDataURL();
            link.href = document.getElementById(canvasId).toDataURL();
            link.download = filename;
window.open(test);
        }

        /** 
         * The event handler for the link's onclick event. We give THIS as a
         * parameter (=the link element), ID of the canvas and a filename.
        */
        document.getElementById('download').addEventListener('click', function() {
            downloadCanvas(this, 'can', 'signature.png');
        }, false);
</script>
<meta><meta><meta charset="utf-8"></head>
<body onload="init()">
    <canvas width="400" height="200" id="can" style="border: 2px solid currentColor; left: 10px; top: 10px; position: absolute; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"></canvas>
    <div style="left: 450px; top: 10px; position: absolute;">Choose Color</div>
    <div id="black" style="background: black; left: 550px; top: 15px; width: 19px; height: 19px; position: absolute;" onclick="color(this)"></div>
    <div style="left: 450px; top: 40px; position: absolute;">Eraser</div>
    <div id="white" style="background: white; border: 2px solid currentColor; left: 550px; top: 45px; width: 15px; height: 15px; position: absolute;" onclick="erase()"></div>
    <img id="canvasimg" style="left: 52%; top: 10%; position: absolute;">
    <a class="button" id="download" style="left: 10px; top: 220px; position: absolute;" onclick="downloadCanvas(this, 'can', 'test.png')" href="#">Download</a>


</body></html>
```

Comment: Which version(s) of IE are you targeting?

Comment: @nnnnnn I'm using IE11

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[FINAL ANSWER/EDIT]**

Open a new window, and set the **innerHTML** property of the **body** to:

```
<img src="[DATA URI GOES HERE]"/>
```

---

According to MSDN, the toDataURL() method works in IE >= 9.

canvasElement.toDataURL(imageMimeType,quality)

imageMimeType can be "image/png", " image/jpg", "image/webp" and I believe "image/gif" as well.

To achieve what you wish to do, you could set an anchor with the href of the canvas data URI, or even use window.open to open the data URI in a new tab.

**Saving Image in Same Tab**: [Another StackOverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15931341/saving-canvas-locally-in-ie)

**Resources for Data URIs**:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/data_URIs

Comment: The quality of the image for JPEG, ranging from 0.0-1

Comment: Done that just keeps opening a new window with nothing on it

Comment: Really? In Chrome at least, opening a dataURI in a new tab displays the image. Ex. window.open(canvasElement.toDataURL('image/png'));

Comment: If that really doesn't work in IE, what you could do is something along the lines of this in JavaScript:

var docString = '<html><body><img src="'+canvasElement.toDataURL("image/png")+'"/></body></html>';

var win = window.open("_blank");

win.contentDocument.write(docString);

Comment: These look like they might be helping, I think the issue is compatibility mode, bare with me whilst I try this

Comment: If all else fails, you can still save the image in the same tab. I added some useful links to my answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67848/discussion-between-rickyayoder-and-crouch).