# How to stream a file to the hard drive?

Tags: javascript, html, file-io

I would like to read data from a service, decrypt it in the browser, then write it out. Reading from the service and decrypting are easy enough to do, but how can I ask the user where to download the file?

I found the FileSystem and FileWriter API but that's not widely supported (just Chrome, Opera and Safari). I've been looking into [Downloadify](https://github.com/dcneiner/Downloadify) at the recommendation of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3916191/download-data-url-file) but it seems I have to have the entire file in memory before I can start the download. Aside from that, it works great. However, I want to set it up as a stream. Get a chunk from the service, decrypt that chunk, write that chunk to disk before getting another chunk.

How can I stream data from javascript to disk? I'm sure it's possible because Mega.co.nz works this way. I've tried going through their code but to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually came across [FileSaver.js](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js), a wonderful little library to do exactly what I'm wanting to do. It provides a simple `saveAs(blob, filename)` function to save content from javascript to the hard drive using a save file dialog just as if the user were downloading something from a server except no server is required. It works for reasonably large files which are listed in a table on their site. Most browsers seem to work with up to at least 345 MB files. [There's a blog post](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2011/08/Saving-generated-files-on-the-client-side) by the author with a great break down of it's usage.