# How to trigger downloading file from a href manually

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a requirement to get the file from an API which is returning filedata in base64 format.  I am adding that to `<a href` tag that looks like below

```
<a id="myFile" href="data:image/png;base64,..." click="downloadFile()">Download File</a>
```

So I want to trigger filedownload using `$('#myFile').click()` which is going to `downloadFile()` function, but I can't use location.href as I don't want the page to be redirected.

Is there any alternative for this requirement? Any suggestions would be a great help.

NOTE: I am getting href value dynamically with some ajax response once the link is clicked, initially href is set to # and will be replaced with appropriate downloadable string as above. I want to trigger file download along with the same event that triggered ajax request and not with a separate click event.

Comment: Limited browser support. Here is a Chrome only solution. http://stackoverflow.com/a/15832662/5496966 .. You could also replace the application type from `data:image/png` to `data:application/octet-stream` .. it forces the browser to download instead of navigating to the href value.

Comment: Also that may download a bin file. You will have to give it a name and a filetype with whatever method you go with.

Comment: Awsome Ankith. This really worked. Is there anyway to make it multibrowser. Just mention it in regular answer, will mark it right. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Think you should switch out manually to automatically in your title. Manually means user must click on the link to save it

Answer (score 4):

Just create, click and delete a new link in the DOM after the ajax request is complete. Should work.

Here is a link to a [JS fiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/thelessergeek/t38r4tho/).

```
// execute this after the ajax request is complete

var myFile = document.getElementById('myFile');
var dataURI = myFile.getAttribute('href');

myFile.addEventListener("click", function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  // check if href value exists
  if(dataURI.length) {
    var fileName = 'image.png';
    var link = document.createElement("a");
    link.setAttribute("href", dataURI);
    link.setAttribute("download", fileName);    
    document.body.appendChild(link);
    link.click();
    document.body.removeChild(link);
    delete link;
  }
});
```

**Note**: Browsers may not support the filename set in download attribute if there are Cross Origin Requests.

Comment: It's unnecessary to convert a base64 url to a object url

Comment: Thanks! Updated. I was looking at how they are treated. That sort of left me confused.

Answer (score 3):

You can just use the `download` attribute - no JS required.

```
<a id="myFile" href="data:image/png;base64,..." download>Download File</a>
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#attr-download

Comment: This is not what I am looking at. I added a note to my initial request. My actual request is to download the file with an ajax request. Ajax request ad Download file should happen at the same click event.

Comment: I still think you should add the download attribute (with a name also) and when the link's href has been created call `myFile.click()` to download it automatically when the ajax is done

Comment: The initial value is `#` so on click the page reloads, which is not what he wants. He has a script set to change the href value on the first click, which creates a need to preventdefault .. So he cannot use the download attribute.

Comment: Also download is a HTML5 tag which will not work for many of the older versions.

Comment: I'm gonna say that in modern frameworks, this is a far cleaner approach. In Angular I had a similar challenge and this was all it took: <a [href]="link" [download]="file.name">

Answer (score 2):

If you include [FileSaver](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js) in your page then you can do something like

```
fetch(url).then(res => res.blob()).then(blob => saveAs(blob, 'filename.txt'))
```