# how to download excel from byte 64 Excel string i in browser using javascript

Tags: javascript, download

I tried using this but not working. How to achieve it? I want to download in the browser. `window.open("data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64," + string);`

Also... My PDF is not opening in IE `data:application/PDF;base64,`

Working in Chrome.

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3916191/download-data-url-file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used this with great success:
https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/

I've also used xlsx-js.js to create xlsx files in the browser and then download: https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx

You do not need node.js for either one, you can use both libraries in the browser.