# Download image obtained from chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, chrome-app-developer-tool

From

```
chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab()
```

i get *dataURL*

How can i download this image by using javascript?

Comment: [Download data url file](//stackoverflow.com/a/15832662)

Comment: does dataURL have unique id or name for image?

Comment: No, I don't think so.

Comment: So, user should provide a name for image. Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Download data url file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3916191/download-data-url-file)