# iam having an api url this is my url path "http://127.0.0.1:8000/uploads/isv/isv_marketplace/2017-08-23-10-56-08/Partner_Welcome_email.html"

Tags: python, typescript

iam having an api url this is my url path  "http://127.0.0.1:8000/uploads/isv/isv_marketplace/2017-08-23-10-56-08/Partner_Welcome_email.html" from this iam able to view the file  it works i dont know how to download i really struct here please help me iam using typescript

Comment: could you please elaborate ? it is really hard to understand what the error is without knowing anything about your environment

Comment: basically iam using angular2 typescript in my backend using python..while doing api call.it returning values from backend .from the backend data.i retrived a file path above which i mentioned..while adding that path in anchor tag it will showing the file in new tab but for what i need is i need to download that file depends upon the type eg(image/jp or html/txt)depends hope u understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try out this answer. It may helpful https://stackoverflow.com/a/15832662/7491209

It shows how to download file from given url