# Unable to generate a file to download with Django

Tags: python, ajax, django, file, proto

**Part which is working fine** :

I have made a `<form>` whose submit call makes an `ajax` request.Code for the same :

```
 $.ajax({

            type: 'POST',
            url: '/uploaded_proto_file/',
            data: formdata,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,

            success: function (data) {
                console.log("in success")
                console.log("data is --->"+data)
                return;

            },
            error: function (data) {
                console.log("in error")

                return;
            }

        });
```

I am able to receive the call for the same on the function below. Now i need to send a file (which is in my document structure) that needs to auto downloaded in my browser. I execute this function based on this [answer](http://www.stackoverflow/a/909088)

```
def uploaded_proto_file(request):
   with open(
            '/Users/metal/Documents/test_pb2.py','rb') as text_file:
        response = HttpResponse(FileWrapper(text_file.getvalue()), content_type='application/zip')
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=test_pb2.py'
        return response
```

The above code wasn't working fine, so I debugged it and found this error on the `filewrapper` statement

[image: snapshot of error]

Now I changed the solution a bit but the file sent back in response is not getting auto downloaded , it is getting printed in the console (as my success block in ajax function has console.log(data))
**Changed solution :**

```
with open(
            '/Users/metal/Documents/test_pb2.py','rb') as text_file:
        response = HttpResponse(text_file, content_type='application/zip')
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=test_pb2.py'
        return response
```

As you can see above I removed `FileWrapper` and was atleast able to send the file back to `ajax` request. But the problem still persists as the file is not getting auto downloaded.

P.S. : I have also tried opening the `file` in different modes like 'r','rb'.

Any help would be appreciated !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't return a file to an ajax request and expect it to be downloaded. What you need is to separate into a few steps:

- Your ajax request triggers the file creation process
- Django puts that file somewhere where it can be downloaded and returns the URL to the file as ajax response
- Your js response handler can now do two things:

  1. Generate a button in the HTML for the user to click and download the file (using the URL from the response)
  2. Create the button and auto-click it (call `.click()` on it) and then delete it again. A bit like in [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3916191/download-data-url-file#15832662)

Comment: I understood the second part but is there a way I can do it without the downloadable url , I dont want to upload the file somewhere else and then pass the url when I already have the file content in my success block

Comment: Actually, if you look at the example linked in my response, you can use a data URI in your download button, so maybe try that.