# Making a downloadable file with the dataURL

Tags: javascript, html, data-uri

I am trying to make a downloadable file from only a dataURL and I am not sure why it is not working. I am reading the dataURL from a file and inserting its dataURL into an  with the download attribute. but when i generate de click the page goes blank and says it can´t find the page. Here is how I am trying to do it.

```
reader.readAsDataURL(file);
reader.onload = function (evt) {
    var element = document.createElement('a');
    element.setAttribute('href', evt.target.result);
    var name=filename.split(".");
    element.setAttribute('download', 'filename');

    element.style.display = 'inline-block';
    document.body.appendChild(element);

    element.click();

    document.body.removeChild(element);
 }
```

From the code above I obtain this

[image]

How can I properly make a download action for the dataURL?

Comment: Can you please share your HTML code?

Comment: I get the file from this html form:                                                                   
                             <label for="archivoC">ChooseFile</label>
                            <input type="file" class="form-control-file" id="archivoC">

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75244388/1243247

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is wrong.

> The readAsDataURL method is used to read the contents of the specified Blob or File.
>   The result will be  base64 encoded string.

The readAsDataUrl method can be used to make a image preview.

To download the file you can go by this approach

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head> </head>
  <body>
     <form>
        <label for="file">ChooseFile</label>
        <input type="file" id="myFile" accept="image/*">
    </form>

    <script>
        document.getElementById("myFile").addEventListener("change", downloadFile);

        function downloadFile() {            
            let file = this.files[0];
            let url = URL.createObjectURL(file);

            let link = document.createElement('a');
            link.href = url;
            link.download = file.name;
            link.click();
            link = null;

            URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
        }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Useful resources**

- [FileReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader)
- [createObjectURL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL)
- [revokeObjectURL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/revokeObjectURL)