# Saving canvas to png: Is it possible to remove MIME type warning message in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, mime-types

I'm trying to save canvas as image.

Everything works fine, but I get a warning message in the browser:
"Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type image/octet-stream ..."

I use the following code:

```
let img = canvas
  .toDataURL("image/png")
  .replace("image/png", "image/octet-stream");
window.location.href = img;
```

Is it possible to make the browser not give this warning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chrome doesn't recognize `image/octet-stream`. The MIME type for arbitrary binary data is [`application/octet-stream`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2046#section-4.5.1).

But you don't have arbitrary binary data, you have a PNG in a data URL. [There are more user-friendly ways to download that.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15832662)