# How to "save as" truncated output in google chrome console

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

[image: Console output]

So in the picture I have my google chrome console output. I want to save it to a file. Right-clicking "Save as" works BUT does not save the part that is hidden under "Show more".

How can I save the entire output of the console, not only the visible part?

Comment: Perhaps you could trigger a download instead of console.log? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3916191/download-data-url-file

Comment: It's a bug in devtools, you can report it in https://crbug.com.