# How can I change JSON file with javascript

Tags: javascript, json, web

I want to change my JSON file or add an element to my SON file, but real file. I tried this code, but it doesn't work on the real file. Only the time the tab is open on the web has changed. How to handle it in real file? Not user file, it is server file, but I tried my local.

```
let xmlreq = new XMLHttpRequest()
xmlreq.open("GET","users.json",true)
 function test(){ 
const obj = JSON.parse(xmlreq.responseText); 
console.log(obj);
obj.user1.name="john";
console.log('obj.user1.name: ', obj.user1.name);

obj.user2.push("item");
console.log('obj.user2.: ', obj.user2);
}

xmlreq.send()
```

another

```
    let xmlreq = new XMLHttpRequest()
function test(){ 
// let parsereq= JSON.parse(xmlreq.responseText);
const obj = JSON.parse(xmlreq.responseText); 
console.log(obj);
obj.user1.name="john";
console.log('obj.user1.name: ', obj.user1.name);

obj.user2.push("item");
console.log('obj.user2.: ', obj.user2);
}


xmlreq.open("GET","users.json",true)
xmlreq.send()
```

Comment: It's not exactly clear from your question. But in case you are trying to change a file in the user's harddrive, you can't. Unless you are running a server that accepts files and replaces them you have no access to writing or changing any files

Comment: By the way, you can include code (and images too) directly in your question, you don't need to use image links.

Comment: Also, I don't see how your code would change anything the the json there? You define a function test and never call it. And then you are doing a get request, that's it

Comment: @AramBecker you can see i am new on this site so I can't upload photos directly and i try a database for users .just try on my computer , not the user computer , You can think of it as a server.

Comment: I still don't understand what you are trying to achieve. Can you provide the json input, the desired json output and what exactly you mean by save?

Comment: @AramBecker Sorry, my fault, I didn't explain myself properly. What I want to do is to print data to a .json file using javascript. I hope I can explain now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you have to use the File API to load the file.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File

Then you have to parse the JSON data.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse

Then you can do your modifications.

But you can not modify files on your local disc directly. Instead you have to download the file in order to overwrite the original file.

To do so you have to create a data URL from your JSON data.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs

And finally you can create a link to download the new JSON.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/15832662/402322