# Onclick save drawing for Javascript in <script> element

Tags: javascript

```
 function save() {
    document.getElementById("canvasimg").style.border = "2px solid";
    var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();
    document.getElementById("canvasimg").src = dataURL;
    document.getElementById("canvasimg").style.display = "inline";
}
```

wich will creat a new picture to the right but i want it to download right away i think you would have to use

```
<a href="x" download>
```

but what would x be for the download and how would i set it to download on click

The Comment

Does this answer your question? Download data URL file –
Harshit Rastogi

i tried to use that code but it says it has an error trying to download im using github so i think it tried to download the site i made.
[The error in the bottom right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1qM63.png)

here is the website ive been trying for it to work
its a little messy but in the middle is the drawing
https://bobzilla07.github.io/web-platform-j1pnv3/

Comment: It would be the data URL. You can create the `a` tag dynamically (doesn't even have to be visible), set its `src` as well as a `download` attribute, and call `.click()` on it to trigger the download synthetically.

Comment: so would it be `<a href="dataURL" download>` ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Download data URL file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3916191/download-data-url-file)

Comment: No, not statically a string called `dataURL`. It would have to be set dynamically at runtime (using `setAttribute` or your framework's method of choice, if any).