# How to force js in React to Download Files?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, download, callback

Using just Html is not possible. I need to download using a callback function, but it's not working.

```
  const downloadImage = ( dataURL: string, fileName: string ) => {
    const link = document.createElement('a')
    link.download = fileName
    link.href = dataURL
    link.click()
  }
```

Return..

```
 <button className="btn btn-primary btn-sm" onClick={() => downloadImage('https://estica-public.s3.amazonaws.com/21965/conversions/8b3ujv9ze8d0uho287bq182zgpvv-full.png?X-Amz-Content-Sha256=UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAY2EWNM3MQCGRS66O%2F20221111%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20221111T135108Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Expires=3600&X-Amz-Signature=9e11f9af9fc1ba81f3100a2da6d29a6fd71e3b5a7a9e5b7682dc5171530b251a', 'image.png')} >Baixar arte gráfica</button>
```

Please guys, help me, I tried every tutorial on Youtube and here on StackOverflow.

I tried html method, using labs, but I really need to do this code works, someone please could help me?
I already tried every method here on StackOverflow, so I put the method I'm using to force it to download and the link I must embebed in my project.

Answer (score 1):

Try to encapsulate the button with an `<a>` element like:

```
<a href="https://path.to.your.file.com" target="_blank" rel="noreferrer">
  <button>Click</button>
</a>
```

**Edit thanks to Disco comment:**

```
<a href="https://path.to.your.file.com" target="_blank" rel="noreferrer" download>
  <button>Click</button>
</a>
```

Comment: thanks for the answear, but this method is using HTML, and browsers when the project become big don't download it, it just open a new tab, that's the reason I needed to create a callback function to force the browser to download, but it's not working :/

Comment: You can also leverage the download attribute: download="file_name"
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_download.asp

Comment: it doesn't work too, just open the image in a new tab :/

Comment: the method more similar that might work is this https://stackoverflow.com/a/45905238

Comment: but something is missing in mycode and doesn't work