# How to download .js file by JavaScript from an url?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I know this question is asked hundreds of time in this forum, But I'm trying to download a `.js` file from an url in my Vue 2 application, but it's not working. Here is what I'm trying:

```
downloadScript() {
      ApiService.post(`url`).then((res) => {    // axios
        try {
          // Create a new link
          const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([res.data.path]));
          const anchor = document.createElement("a");
          anchor.href = url;.js";
          anchor.setAttribute("download", "script.js");
          document.body.appendChild(anchor);
          anchor.click();
        } catch {
         //
        }
      });
    },
```

This downloads a file which consists nothing but the url I've provided to the axios post request.

I'm getting API response like following:

```
{
    "success": true,
    "path": "https://something.com/files/iq-return.min.js"
}
```

I've to donwload the script in a file from the `path`

Comment: What would be the use case?

Comment: I just want to download the .js file like any other file(for example .pdf).

Comment: Then, [that one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67118753/8816585) would be enough. No need for `createObjectURL` and `new Blob`.

Comment: This opens the JS in a new page, not downloading it @kissu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`new Blob([res.data.path])` creates a Blob (which is sort-of-like-a-file) containing the text in the string you pass it.

Since that text is a URL, the file you download is a text file containing that URL.

If you want to create a Blob containing the JavaScript source code, then you need to *get the JS source code*. Make an HTTP request to the URL (e.g. with `fetch`) and put the response body in the Blob.

(Aside: don't append `.js` to the generated URL with you set `href`, that modifies the contents of the file!)

This will, of course, require permission from [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) if this is a cross-origin request.

If it *isn't* a cross-origin request then you can just set the `href` attribute to `res.data.path` without leaping through all these hoops.