# Download and add .vcf to address book iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios4

I have a mobile website which allows user to add me to their mobile contacts by downloading .vcf contact into their iOS device but on iphone safari gives an error "Safari could not download file". Any help how to solve this idea (I think send this via email is possible but that is not a good solution according to my PM)

thank you guys

Best Regards

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1773876/how-to-add-a-contact-to-the-iphones-address-book-from-a-web-page