# How to get contact information when creating a contact from TEL URI

Tags: jquery, ios, html, jquery-mobile, tel

Assuming I have an HTML table with these info (writing as text but it's html behind):

```
lastname: MyName
firstname: MyFirstName
tel: 04 50 12 34 56
email : bla@mail.com
```

In html I wrote the tel field like that :

```
<a href="tel:+33450123456">04 50 12 34 56</a>
```

When i'm on iOS, if I click on the anchor it asks me if I want to call or create contact. 
I want then to create a contact with all my informations already filled.
Any idea? Only with HTML or JS or JQM please

Comment: Related: [Address book - how to add a contact to iPhone's address book from a web-page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1773876/how-to-add-a-contact-to-the-iphones-address-book-from-a-web-page).

Comment: Related: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/22177/importing-vcards-from-a-website-into-ioss-contacts-app

Comment: It's not like vCard, i want it to be pure web based.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure this isn't possible. iOS has a bunch of url schemes included in Safari that you can take advantage of, but adding a complete new contact isn't one of them.

More information on the available schemes here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Articles/PhoneLinks.html

Comment: "bunch" is not enough. I already use tel anchor but the thing I want is to tag elements like for a username/password in a form or an address form in chrome. I want Safari to get the name, lastname and such automatically from my form if you prefer

Comment: And my answer is that it's not possible, unless - like user1132647 above is assuming - you are using PhoneGap. I was simply linking you to a page that explained about URI schemes and listed the ones that were possible to show you that what you want to do isn't possible.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [PhoneGap's Contact API](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.4.1/phonegap_contacts_contacts.md.html#Contact).  There is a save method method that you can call.

Just bind an click handler to the anchor tag and put the code to invoke the PhoneGap API in the handler.