# Is it possible to make iPhone recognize a Contact's name belonging to a phone number on a web page?

Tags: iphone, html

I'm building a simple web page with contacts and their phone numbers.
When accessing the page from an iPhone the iPhone recognizes the number
and when the user touches the phone number a call is started.
When the call is finished and the user want to save the number in the 
phone book (Make new Contact), I would like to have the name of the contact
pre filled into name field of phone book entry.

Is it possible to make iPhone recognize the name belonging to a phone number on the web page? Is there a meta or XML tag that let iPhone identify the name from the web page?

Best regards
Will

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately not. The best way to do this would be to serve up a vCard, but Safari doesn't support them for security reasons. The closest I've found is [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1892373/iphone-how-to-get-safari-to-recognize-a-vcard), but the closet solution there involves returning an ics (iCal) file with a vCard embedded inside it. This is not ideal.

So to summarise, there isn't a way to do this at present. This question has a lot of good information as well:

[How to add a contact to the iPhone's Address Book from a Web Page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1773876/how-to-add-a-contact-to-the-iphones-address-book-from-a-web-page)

If you are building your webpage with a view to embedding it inside a native app there are other options, but it sounds like that's not the case.